# CoffeeScript used in Codepen.io does not work in Internet Explorer anymore

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coffeescript, codepen

I created a lot of code examples on Codepen.io in the past years. I used CoffeeScript instead of JavaScript, and the examples usually worked in both Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

A few weeks ago, I checked again in Internet Explorer, but they do not seem to work anymore.

Take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/accessibility-developer-guide/pen/BxxrBj

In Internet Explorer, the console says "Syntax error":

[image]

The erroneous code is:

[image]

I see the `=>` there, which seems to be a problem. But in other browsers, this seems to work.

The original code is nothing fancy:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $button = $("button")
  $tooltip = $("#tooltip")

  $button.click =>
    if $tooltip.attr("hidden") == "hidden"
      $tooltip.removeAttr("hidden")
      $button.attr("aria-expanded", true)
    else
      $tooltip.attr("hidden", true)
      $button.attr("aria-expanded", false)
```

Has there been any recent change to how Codepen.io compiles its CoffeeScript? Maybe to a JavaScript version that is not supported by Internet Explorer anymore?

Is there a way to change this back to a compatible version?

Comment: IE doesn't support arrow `=>` functions

Comment: But I remember that a few months ago, I created similar pens that used to work in IE. I though that `=>` are some internal CoffeeScript thing that would be converted to something similar in JavaScript that used to work in IE?

Comment: If you use e.g. Babel to convert an arrow function, you'll see what it becomes.

Comment: Thank you. It still feels awkward that some months ago everything seemed to work on codepen in IE, now it doesn't anymore. Maybe they updated the compiler that dropped backwards compatibility?

Comment: Maybe they did...just tried to suggest a reasonable workaround instead of chasing what they might or might not change.